# Linerenderer on canvas doesn't show properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I am currently working on a game, and i've run into the following problem:

I want to draw some results as a graph on top of my Canvas and so far i've found out that my Canvas needs to be in Screenspace-Camera for this to work, as the LineRenderer is a 3D-Object and will be covered by Screenspace-Overlay otherwise.

And i've actually got it to work with this, looks like the following:
[image: LineRenderer in front of canvas]

But the problem i've encountered is that if i increase the screen size, e.g. by stretching the GameView or maximizing it, the line disappears, even though it has a negative z compared to all my UI elements and therefore appears in front of them in the EditorView:

[image: Screenshot of full editor window]

If i try to fix this by applying a greater negative z-Value relative to the screen size the lines get distorted, as they are getting closer and closer to the camera, and changing their alignment from view to z-Axis didn't help either.

What makes this even more confusing is that this happen to lines that are drawn lower (smaller y-value) first, meaning a line at the bottom of my graph disappears earlier. I really don't know why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a z buffer issue, Dave's advice is good, one other thing you can try is to put a different shader on the object.

Comment: Will try that, but i also hoped to find out the reason for this behaviour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3D objects mixed with UI elements I recommend using a separate camera with greater depth than the camera drawing standard ui elements. This way your 3D objects will always be rendered on top of the UI elements and you wont have to worry about Z positions.

Comment: Seems like a viable option. I will try that.

Comment: Its worked just fine, and its probably also good practice to separate 3D and 2D Objects. I doubt there will be a better answer as this is quite the specific question, accepted.