# So I see the line in scene but not in game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

[image]

The following is my code for context but I wanted the preview of the line that I see in the scene view shown on the game to see if the line is working.

```
public class tapLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    private bool isDrawing = false;
    private Vector3 startPoint;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                StartDrawing(touch.position);
            }
            else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && isDrawing)
            {
                UpdateDrawing(touch.position);
            }
            else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && isDrawing)
            {
                EndDrawing();
            }
        }
    }

    private void StartDrawing(Vector3 startPos)
    {
        isDrawing = true;
        startPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(startPos);
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 1;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, startPoint);
    }

    private void UpdateDrawing(Vector3 currentPos)
    {
        Vector3 worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(currentPos);
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, worldPosition);
    }

    private void EndDrawing()
    {
        isDrawing = false;
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line do you refer to?

Comment: @shingo I would guess the selected one in the image

Comment: @derHugo perhaps the orange border?

Comment: @shingo I think the orange border outlines the selected "line" OP is referring to yes

Comment: Are those other contents also `LineRenderer`? Or are those rather UI components like `Image` etc -> in that case why not rather use an `Image` for your line as well? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280558/how-to-draw-a-line-on-top-of-a-panel-use-screen-space-overlay-canvas, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855494/linerenderer-on-canvas-doesnt-show-properly and similar related posts

Comment: The vertical lines are images that are not used in the code so please ignore them. The issue I'm having is when a user taps and drags the line; the line appears in the scene view but not the game view. This game object uses a line renderer  .@derHugo

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this occurrence lies in the behavior of Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(). It delivers a non-zero value on the Z axis, considering depth as a factor. Hence, the challenge at hand is the non-zero Z axis. To resolve this matter, you need to incorporate the following code line whenever you employ Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint():

```
worldPosition.z = 0;
```

worldPosition represents the variable assigned to store the world position obtained from the camera. By including this line, you guarantee that the Z axis remains consistently set to zero.